# PrimeNG - Change the treeTable leaf nodes color

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-treetable

I have a treeTable and I need to change the colors of the leaf nodes (has no children). Is this possible ?

I tried to apply some style classes from dataModel, but it seems it's not working. I also tried to create a condition on columns based on a dataModel field.

*example*

```
 <p-column field="name" [styleClass]="coloredColumn"  *ngIf="leafNode == true"></p-column> 
 <p-column field="name"                               *ngIf="leafNode != true"></p-column>
```